# FFMpeg live stream with C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, frames, libavformat

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern “C” {
#include “libavformat\avformat.h”
#include “libavdevice\avdevice.h”
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  av_register_all(); 
  avcodec_register_all(); 
  avdevice_register_all();
  avformat_network_init(); 
  AvFormatContex *pFormatContex;
  pFormatContext = format_alloc_context();
  AvInputFormat * a = av_find_input_format(“dshow”);
  av_format_open_input(&pFormatCtx, “video””HP Webcam [2 MP Fixed]”””,a,NULL); 
}
```

This code is the access web cam. 
I want to live stream on web cam in C++. I can't get web cam video on web cam.